# Smooth function extension and partitions of unity (doubt about Lee's book)

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking at the text by John Lee, Introduction to smooth manifolds, page 44-45. In proposition 2.25 it is proved that if $A\subset U\subset M$ with $A$ closed, $U$ open, $M$ a smooth manifold, then there exists  a smooth function supported in $U$ and equal to 1 on $A$.

Then in Lemma 2.26 it is proved that if $A$, $U$, $M$ are as above and $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ is a smooth function then there exist a smotth function $\tilde f$ on $M$ which is supported in $U$ agrees with $f$ on $A$.

The proof of Lemma 2.26 given in the book is longer then I expected.
I do not see what goes wrong if we just make use of proposition 2.25:
let $\rho$ be a smooth function on $M$ which is supported in $U$ and equal to 1 on $A$ and define
\begin{equation*}
\tilde f (p)= \begin{cases}
\rho(p) f(p) & \text{for $p\in U$},\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

What am I missing?

Comment: $f$ is only defined on $A$, so your function is not defined on $U\setminus A$. The difficulty is that you need to smoothly get to $0$ from $f(p)$, where $p$ is in the boundary of $A$. To achieve that, you need first to _somehow_ extend $f$ smoothly to an open neighbourhood of $A$. Once you have that, you multiply with a smooth cut-off function.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, thank you!